# Android Library project OkHttp3 proguard

Tags: android, proguard, okhttp, android-proguard

I have an android project with a library project module, in which I am using Retrofit with OkHttp3 to do API requests. I need to use Proguard to obfuscate the project, but when I do, I get a huge list of errors relating to OkHttp when trying to build the signed apk:

```
can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
```

I have tried to following rules in both the main app and library project Proguard files, but nothing seems to work:

```
 -dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
 -dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I came across the answer in a comment on GitHub: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/117

I had to use:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard true
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

I then set the rules in the proguard file for the module and it worked without any problems.